# A word similar to "reckless" but where the failure is both unavoidable and unexpected

Tags: meaning, word-choice

An example: I discover there is a fault in my materials but I continue to use them, knowing the result will be a failure but in the hope it will be a success. I should have rejected the materials as they were never going to become good.

Second example: The lawn mower is broken and wont start. I decide to make all the actions and effort of mowing the lawn. I still expect payment as the client should be happy, even though the grass is uncut.

I considered reckless or delusional as close but it is not quite it.

Comment: ***Delusional*** might work - if I were the customer, I can imagine saying *You must be **delusional / off your rocker / bonkers!*** if someone expected me to pay them for a job they didn't do. But I can't see how  ***reckless*** would fit (unless you're implying that the dissatisfied customer might be so angry he might physically attack you or sue you). Or I might just go for some serious British understatement, and limit myself to saying *I think you're being a bit overoptimistic expecting payment, my good man!*

Comment: delusional doesnt work because the person is skilled (an expert even).

Comment: Experts can certainly be delusional. But even people who aren't "expert tradesmen" would probably realize that most people don't expect to pay a tradesman who doesn't do the job he was hired for.

Comment: I believe they know that the work was bad though but they made the correct level of effort. They are trying to pass it off. Delusional could be the insult from the customer to the vendor but I am trying to find a word for the act from the third party perspective.

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Comment: I'd call this *going through the motions of  ...*. I once helped build a house that was laid out 1 foot out-of-square. The blocklayer was the first to spot it. Everyone shrugged and kept on building. Sheeting the roof was interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (many overlapping answers at) [Word for fruitless effort?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91662/word-for-fruitless-effort). There are other closely related questions. It's an exercise in futility, though I'm not sure there's a related agent noun.

Comment: At the risk of observing the emperor's navel: what do you mean "failure is ... unexpected"? Also, you're asking about (1) doing something that is likely to end in failure, possibly catastrophic, and (2) doing busy work that is sure to produce no effect. I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around these two concepts enough to lasso them done to a single word, except for broad ones like "stupidity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**in denial**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+denial): in a
>   state of refusing to believe something that is true
>
> [**in denial**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/in-denial): a refusal or
>   unwillingness to accept something or to accept reality

**In denial** works in both examples. Our main character can't quite bring themself to "**know**" or *accept* that what they're doing won't work, while at the same time maintaining a small glimmer of hope that somehow leads them to expect success. Hence:

> **"failure is unavoidable and unexpected"**

Beyond that, the second example involves more craziness than the first, but both involve some craziness.

**Reckless** doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using reckless to me in the form of reckless disregard, a legal term.  You are suggesting to me following through with an action with reckless disregard to the truth that the action will not be successful.  Slightly off from FumbleFingers Delusional which I would see as more, you should know the action will not be successful, but you are allowing yourself to be blind to what the inevitable results will be.

Negligent would be considered a close relative or slightly lessor instance of reckless disregard in the same light.

Comment: I like negligent as it covers it. It's too broad though (unless there is no other word).

Comment: That seems the direction you want, but likely a somewhat softer, less legalistic term.  I am sure they exist, but none that seem to fit are coming to me.  I am sure another may hit a word or phrase that is more correct for what you want.

Comment: In at least some cases In the U.S. (e.g., Nuclear Regulatory Commission enforcement policy), we use the term **careless disregard**, which connotes a form of extreme negligence.